# for loop to populate dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I'm trying to populate a dataframe with the result of a for-loop, but I'm missing something. I've looked at the past questions about this, but I can't get my head around the solution, so...

The fictional data:

```
df <- data.frame(RA = c(rep("14005", 3), rep("14158", 3), rep("15458", 2), rep("15302", 2)),
             Level = c(rep("Grad", 6), rep("Undergrad", 4)),
             EntryYear = c(rep(2014, 6), rep(2015, 4)),
             ExitYear = c(rep(2016, 3), rep(2017, 3), rep(2018, 4)))
```

I want to fill a data frame with the result of a specific dplyr pipeline:

```
df %>% 
filter(Level == "Grad", EntryYear <= year, ExitYear >= year) %>% 
distinct(RA) %>% 
summarise(year = n())
```

Where year is the specific year I'm interested (in my original data, it goes from 2010 to 2017). The formula above is to calculate, roughly, how many students are registered in the given year. [I'll use two more formulas, to calculate the number of graduates and freshmen, so I'll have two more row/columns]. And:

```
start.year <- 2010
end.year <- 2017
```

So, I made this for-loop, to see if it works:

```
for (year in start.year:end.year){
  mat <- df %>% 
    filter(Level == "Grad", EntryYear <= year, ExitYear >= year) %>% 
    distinct(RA) %>% 
    summarise(year= n())
  print(mat)
}
```

It does print what I want, but then I'm not able to write it into a dataframe... The expected result is a dataframe with 7 rows. The **final** result is a dataframe with 7 rows and 3 columns (the two other formulas/pipelines that I'll apply).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are already using `dplyr`, it is easy to also use `purrr` to merge the data.frames for you

```
library(purrr)
map_df(start.year:end.year, function(year) {
  mat <- df %>% 
    filter(Level == "Grad" & EntryYear <= year & ExitYear >= year) %>% 
    distinct(RA) %>% 
    summarise(year= n())
})
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thanks! I've never used purrr before - guess I'll become acquainted with it.

Comment: Let me seize the opportunity: I'm trying to add another column to my newly created dataframe, but it only returns the last variable that I created... How do I do it all inside this function?

Answer (score 1):

Just add these two lines in your final code:

```
new_df <- data.frame(). # <- this one
for (year in start.year:end.year){
    mat <- df %>% 
        filter(Level == "Grad", EntryYear <= year, ExitYear >= year) %>% 
        distinct(RA) %>% 
        summarise(year= n())
    new_df <- rbind(new_df, mat) # <- this one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (year in start.year:end.year){
  mat <- df %>% 
    filter(Level == "Grad", EntryYear <= year, ExitYear >= year) %>% 
    distinct(RA) %>% 
    summarise(year= n())
  print(mat)

  if (year<2011){

    final <- as.data.frame(mat)

  }

  else{

    final <- rbind(final,as.data.frame(mat))

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# load packages
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# Filter function
filterdf<-function(year, level){
  mat <- df %>% 
    filter(Level == level, EntryYear <= year, ExitYear >= year) %>% 
    distinct(RA) %>% 
    summarise(year= n())
  colnames(mat)<-paste0(level, "_number")
  return(mat)
}

# Create your input conditions
input<-as.data.frame(seq(2010,2017))
colnames(input)<-"year"
input$level<-"Grad"

# Output to a dataframe
output<-mdply(input,filterdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` alternative:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(Level=="Grad") %>%
  mutate(year = map2(EntryYear,ExitYear,~.x:.y)) %>%
  unnest(year) %>%
  distinct(RA,year) %>%
  count(year)

# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#    year     n
#   <int> <int>
# 1  2014     2
# 2  2015     2
# 3  2016     2
# 4  2017     1
```